# Can we write Android code using netbeans

Tags: android, netbeans

Can I write Android code in Netbeans IDE same as Eclipse IDE. Is this possible. Please help me, If you have any idea about that so please share with me.

Comment: I haven't try it, but answer is yes, search old posts on SO :)

Comment: Check this out: http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid

Comment: Next time, google it before asking a question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can.
There is an unofficial [netbeans plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/19545/nbandroid).
Right now, [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) is clearly the focus of the Android Tools team attention and is going to be the most feature complete IDE for Android development in the foreseeable future.
Code with whatever fits your need, just keep in mind that you might not get all of AS Android tools in Netbeans.

Comment: The best option seems to be Android Studio. I know it did not exist at the time when you wrote your answer, but it does now :)

Comment: @KonradMorawski yeah, AS did not exist when I wrote my answer and it was still in alpha when you wrote yours, but it is now clearly the IDE of the future for Android development. I have edited my answer to reflect that.